# How do I manage AWS cognito code grant flow on the frontend using the hosted ui

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I would like to use Amazon cognito as a way to allow users to sign up to my app and validate api calls, so I don't have to handle user passwords or create a custom account recovery email system.
The problem is im not sure I understand how its supposed to work or what tools I am meant to use. Heres how I imagine it:

[image]

This way I could use cognito to identify users and authorize api calls.
But I am not sure if this is correct. For example I'm not sure if the frontend is supposed to refresh the tokens or the backend.
I am also not sure if I am meant to implement the code for exchanging and refreshing the token and logging out of users myself, but it seems that way since I can't find any tools that would do that for me.
I have found some libraries concerning aws cognito, but none of them mention exchanging or refreshing tokens:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-auth-js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-cdk/aws-cognito

I did find this library mentioned in the documentation that can be used to validate jwt id tokens on the backend.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-jwt-verify

I am using userpools and no identity pools, since I don't grant users access to my aws resources.

So basically my question is, is my perception of the cognito workflow correct and if yes, how can I exchange the grant code for an id token and how can i use the refresh token to refresh the id token.